# How can I solve numerically this partial differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab, mathematica, simulation

I am reading this [paper](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~othmer/papers/Dallon:1997:DCM.pdf) and came across a system of differential equations with 4 ODEs and 1 PDE. The PDE is given below. My question is how to solve this numerically in MATLAB , Python or Mathematica?

[image]

Here $\tau$ is time, $x$ is a generic point in the plane, subscript $i$ designates the $i$th biological amoeba cell, whose position in the plane is denoted $x_i$, $w_5$ is a extracellular biochemical concentration (cAMP) generated by amoeba, $sr({w_4}^i)$ is the secretion rate function dependent on $w_4$ which is intracellular cAMP concentration,  $\Delta_1$ is the diffusion constant, $\delta(.)$ is the delta function, $\nabla^2(w_5(x))$ is the laplacian, others constants.

Comment: This is a heat equation with lower order adjustments. Look up how to numerically solve heat equations and the same will apply to this equation.

Comment: @aes : What is lower order adjustments?

Comment: The [heat equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) is just the first two terms (the $\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}$ and $\nabla^2$ terms). The rest of the terms don't involve derivatives, i.e. are "lower order" (single derivatives in $x$ would also be lower order). You don't need to worry about this much; it just means techniques for the heat equation will typically apply to yours.

Answer (score 0):

There are packages available for MATLAB do solve partial differential equations 
(e.g.,  Partial Differential Equation Toolbox) but I believe they are add-ons that you have to pay for.